I can't open the settings of the completed operation

Firstly, when I tried to use the "spin" tool, my object was not duplicated as planned, but only rotated, and secondly, when I tried to open the settings of the last operation, it did not work (nothing simply appeared). Well, the display of the operation itself looks compressed, as in the screenshot
